# Couchbase Sync Gateway - limit on number of channels?

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

Does it make sense to define a channel per 1-4 documents?

The use case I am trying to solve is synching user's accounts between different devices of the same user:
For example lets say I have 1 million docs (accounts) in my bucket, then defining 400K channels, a channel for each user. in this example I have 400K users each with 2.5 accounts in average.

Does this sound like a right case for Sync Gateway?

Answer (score 0):

As per CB documentation about [roles](http://docs.pub.couchbase.com/sync-gateway/#roles):

> Roles are named collections of channels. A user account can be
>   assigned to zero or more roles. A user inherits the channel access of
>   all roles it belongs to. This is very much like Unix groups, except
>   that roles do not form a hierarchy.

That would hint me that your approach should be amended and you should design channels with roles in mind. As a result you'll have less channels. You could work out roles like: userGroupA, userGroupB, etc.

In my humble opinion, your approach sounds bit "unscalable" since if number of users grows so does the channels number.